# Load thousands of records into a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datatable

I'm just a newbie, I'm loading the data to display in the view within a datatable, my big problem is that I have more than 1000 records and it takes too long to load so much data, what I would like is to load a certain amount of data and That by means of a paginacion are loading the other data but without losing the dynamic search of the datatable or sorting of the data by columns. Is there any way to do it? No matter if it is with datatable or with some other tool

Comment: [`will_paginate`](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

Comment: for this case was invented pagination

Comment: Would continue to operate the dynamism of the table in terms of the search of datatable and sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Use [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), or simply `.limit(n).offset(m)` where `n`, `m` are numbers > 0

Comment: But using pagination would not be losing the use of dynamic search or sorting in the columns? Or should we apply something else?

Comment: Pagination basically cuts into chuncks whatever goes into "paginate" method, so when it receives an already filtered results (on which you done some searching/filterin/sorting) you will not lose anything.

Comment: Ok but assuming I had 400 records, of which the pagination is going to bring me 10 out of 10, when using the sorting or the datatable finder this would only apply to the 10 records that I brought or applied for all 400 Records?

Comment: All, basically what pagination does in the background is it uses the same .offset and .limit as I've given you as 3rd option. Those two methods simply add to your SQL query (which also includes any ORDER / WHERE clauses) proper clauses. So let say you sort by a user name, and you have 400 records. The query for 1st page would be something like `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username LIMIT 10`, for 2nd `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY username LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`

Comment: Thanks, of all the ones that you mentioned to me which you recommend more that works with datatable? And how could you apply it?

Comment: For an mobile API I myself use only `.limit(x).offset(y)` combination, cos mobile app takes care of pagination. For a webpage both kaminari and will_paginate will work allright, although I've always went for kaminari, simply a matter of preference

Comment: Excellent but how can I apply it? And install the gem, and in the controller place this in the variable users = User.order(:name).page params[:page] and also I see that to show the pagination this should be placed in the view <%= paginate @users %> but I do not know how to apply it because it has its own datatable pagination

Comment: Or can I use the datatable pagination?

Comment: @LuisC kaminari is very well documented, https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#query-basics. I havent used datatable pagination before so cant say whether it will be okay